# Parâmetros para colunas criptografadas

Tags: sql-server, criptografia

Estou tentando criar uma procedure para salvar dados de um usuário no banco de dados SQL SERVER, porém a tabela possui colunas criptografadas com o always encrypted, resultando em um erro de conflito.

Já tentei alterar o tipo dos parâmetros para varbinary etc, mas o erro persiste.

Script de criação da tabela `Usuario` abaixo:

```
CREATE TABLE Usuario(
    idUsuario int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    idCurso int NULL,
    nomeUsuario varchar(30) NULL,
    loginAcademico varchar(30) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = [CEK1], ENCRYPTION_TYPE = Deterministic, ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256') NULL,
    [senhaAcademico] [varchar](20) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = [CEK1], ENCRYPTION_TYPE = Deterministic, ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256') NULL,
    [emailAcessoSistema] [varchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = [CEK1], ENCRYPTION_TYPE = Deterministic, ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256') NULL,
    [senhaSistema] [varchar](20) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = [CEK1], ENCRYPTION_TYPE = Deterministic, ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256') NULL,
    [isAceitouTermos] [bit] NULL,
    [ano] [varchar](4) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [idUsuario] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Usuario]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([idCurso])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Curso] ([idCurso])
ON DELETE SET NULL
GO
```

Erro completo ao criar procedure:

> Msg 206, Nível 16, Estado 2, Procedimento usp_usuario_salvar, Linha 11 [Linha de Início do Lote 7]
>      Conflito no tipo de operando: varchar(30) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'HubbleDB') collation_name = 'Latin1_General_CI_AS' é incompatível com varchar(20) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'HubbleDB') collation_name = 'Latin1_General_BIN2'

[image: Código usado para criação da procedure]

Comment: (**1**) Poderia acrescentar no texto da pergunta como estão declaradas as colunas da tabela `Usuario`? (**2**) Poderia transcrever a mensagem de erro completa?

Comment: Boa noite José, coloquei o script de criação e o erro completo.

Comment: Já tentou deixar as variáveis da procedure com o mesmo tamanho na tabela? varchar(20), varchar(50) e por ai vai?

Comment: @GabrielBastos A princípio me parece conflito de agrupamento (COLLATE). Mas vale também a sugestão do Gabriel Machado (gmsantos), sobre ajustar o tamanho dos parâmetros. // Assim que possível vou simular o cenário em um tamborete, para avaliar possíveis causas.

Comment: @gmsantos era isso mesmo, muito obrigado a todos...

Comment: @GabrielBastos movi o conteudo do comentário para uma resposta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por algum motivo quando você tem colunas encriptadas, ao utilizar as mesma dentro de uma *procedure* o tipo e tamanho da variável deve ser igual ao definido na tabela.

Nesse caso altere os parâmetros da sua *procedure* para combinarem com sua tabela:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_usuario_salvar]
    @loginAcademico varchar(30),
    @senhaAcademico varchar(20),
    @emailAcessoSistema varchar(50),
    @senhaSistema varchar(20),
AS
    INSERT INTO Usuarios(loginAcademico, senhaAcademico, emailAcessoSistema, senhaSistema)
    VALUES(@loginAcademico, @senhaAcademico, @emailAcessoSistema, @senhaSistema)
```